# Append a split button Listview using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a little function that takes an input text and appends it to a listview, it also adds a "delete" button that when pressed it removes the element from the list.
Please find a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/4h857/.

I have been trying do modify this delete function to save some space and to make it look "better" by appending lists with a split button (with the "delete" icon). 
Hoping to get something like in this fiddle I found while searching online http://jsfiddle.net/ffabreti/Q4SCt/1/.

Now I have not made any changes on my fiddle because regardless of what changes I make it would just mess the UI.

Here is the script on my fiddle:

```
$('#AddScript').click(function () {
if ($('#MedNameStren').val() != '') {
    var text = '<h2>' + $('#MedNameStren').val() + '</h2>' + '<button>Delete</button>';
    $('<li />', {
        html: text
    }).appendTo('ul.justList');
    $('button').button();
} else {
    alert('Please fill all fields....');
}
$('ul.ScriptList').listview('refresh')

});

$('ul').on('click', 'button', function (el) {
$(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

I have tried changing `<button>Delete</button>` into `<a href="#">gear</a>` like in the other fiddle but this would not give me the expected results.

I believe I'm doing something very silly, but after hours of research I can't find a example or something that would give me an idea so I can get my head around it and solve it.

I would appreciate any suggestions, please bare with my ignorance as I'm still a jQuery/Mobile newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake, you forgot to add `data-role="listview"` to `ul`. Second mistake, you're calling enhancement `.listview("refresh")` on `ul.ScriptList` which doesn't exist.

The correct markup of a split button is as follows.

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <h2>Text goes here</h2>
    <a href="#"></a> <!-- split button -->
  </a>
</li>
```

You also need to `refresh` list-view after deleting an item to updated styles.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VnTQQ/)**

Comment: Oh damn, sorry I overlooked those errors. Thank you for pointing it out, feel like I learned something new. Great! You saved my life again lol